# respond_to causes undefined method `to_sym' for [:json, :html]:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, respond-to, respond-with

In Rails 3.2.8 in Ruby 1.9.3p194 when passing an array to `respond_to` in an included block of an ActiveSupport::Concern that is included on demand in the class definition by calling an `acts_as_...` method in module included in a gem results in a:

```
respond_to causes undefined method `to_sym' for [:json, :html]:Array
```

and on the next request, I get:

```
RuntimeError (In order to use respond_with, first you need to declare the formats your controller responds to in the class level):
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:234:in `respond_with'
```

In the module code, it is just doing the equivalent of:

```
formats = [:json, :html]
respond_to formats
```

Where formats is configured elsewhere so it can be applied to all controllers that specify `acts_as_...`.

I know it works when I do this in a class definition:

```
respond_to :json, :html
```

So, how can I call respond_to with a variable that is an array of formats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The related parts of the `respond_to` method in Rails 3.2.8 are:

```
def respond_to(*mimes)
  # ...
  mimes.each do |mime|
    mime = mime.to_sym
    # ...
  end
  # ...
end
```

Because the splat operator is used in `respond_to`, it is wrapping the incoming array in an array, so mimes is `[[:json, :html]]`, and it is trying to call `to_sym` on the array.

If calling `respond_to` with a variable containing an array, you need to use the splat (*) operator, e.g.:

```
formats = [:json, :html]
respond_to *formats
```

That will call `respond_to` as if you were sending in two arguments:

```
respond_to :json, :html
```

or:

```
respond_to(:json, :html)
```